# Why setting -r 30 still gives fps=15 in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, framerate

Why setting -r 30 still gives fps=15 in ffmpeg?

command:

```
fmpeg -loglevel verbose -pixel_format mjpeg -s hd720 -r 30 -i /dev/video1 -f libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 23 -f matroska tcp://192.168.1.43:5000
```

output:

```
frame=10497 fps= 15 q=22.0 Lsize=  253990kB time=00:11:39.76 bitrate=2973.4kbit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fps= 15` represents the encoding speed, not the output file framerate.

Comment: What is encoding speed? Sometimes it is fps=30 though. How do I check the frame rate then?

Comment: Shouldn't encoding speed be as fast as output framerate? If it is faster than 30 then maybe it is fine. Now, since it is slower than 30, does it mean I have frame drop?

Comment: `encoding speed` --> number of frames encoded per second, If there are frame drops, you will see `drop=X` in your progress readout, Check the speed, if it's close to `1` then your device is only sending 15 fps.

Comment: I dont see any `drop=X`. How to check speed?

Comment: To the right of bitrate in the progress readout. Increase terminal width if not visible.

Comment: What I get as output is as above. There is no drop=X. Is there special parameter I need to input to get that? Or does it only show when there is drop?

Comment: Only when there is drop.